# How can I download WOFF files from Google Fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, google-font-api

Google Fonts seems to only offer fonts in WOFF2.

While this works fine with Chrome, [WOFF2 doesn't seem to be supported by many other browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2)

Is there a way to directly link to Google fonts hosted on their CDN in a format other than WOFF2?

Comment: [Check this](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Quick_Start) for everything.

Comment: Google serves the file according to the browser, so in most modern browsers you'll get the woff2 version. Use `curl` to get the woff file: `curl 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla'`

Comment: This question is closed now (SO really has to change its policy) but the best answer to this question is this free app https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/f

Comment: Daniel Bang, this did not work for me, I just got CSS for the TTF font.

Comment: @DanielBang … as noted above, the `curl` command downloads files depending on the header and otherwise `TTF`.

Comment: FYI that great heroku app mentioned by @alex-from-jitbit has moved to https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts

Comment: Go to this Google repository and browse the desired font and download in any format. This is an example for 'DM Sans' font. 
https://github.com/googlefonts/dm-fonts/tree/main/Sans/fonts/webfonts

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Unfortunately Google does not offer an easy way to directly download fonts. You can browse the [git repository](https://github.com/google/fonts/) to search for the file you want, though there are only TTF files on GitHub available.

Also, do not directly link to the GitHub hosted fonts in your CSS! GitHub serves the files with the wrong mime type, which causes issues in some browsers.

While there is not a mainstream CDN for all the formats, you can use http://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com to download the font files and host them yourselves.

Comment: Unfortunately [localfont](http://www.localfont.com) doesn't download all charsets of the font. It includes only the Latin charset. [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com) would be better tool for this.

Comment: localfont.com appears to be dead as of July 2017.

Comment: localfont.com is dead, but this alternative works well: https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com

Comment: @AlexeyMitev - you should submit http://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com as an answer.

Comment: @folktrash - I should have but it is too late. The question is closed now.

Comment: I just used Chrome developer tools and set my user agent to an iPhone 5s, and I was served up a woff file.

Comment: Oh the google-webfonts-helper is sooo good :) Thanks for sharing this. It saved me a lot of work!

Comment: Any idea why the fonts served by the Google CDN are so much smaller than if I download them directly using google-webfonts-helper? For example the Latin woff2 version of Open Sans is about 9kb from the CDN but 15kb downloaded. I've tried using a tool to filter the unicode ranges defined in the css file but I only managed to get it down to 14kb.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's just gzipped?

Comment: Imho, it seems the Git Repo only servres TTF, just like the dl button on the font main page. I cannot find any woff2 there. https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/main/ofl/opensans

Answer (score 34):

When I open the following URL in Chrome, I get a link to the font in `woff2` format. When I use Firefox, it's in `woff` format and in an Android device running pre-4.4, it is in `ttf` format.

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans

So it appears that Google delivers fonts in a format appropriate to the requesting user-agent.

Comment: I'm accessing that in Firefox, and the fonts are in woff2 format. Maybe the situation for FF has changed?

Comment: I tried this in safari just now and got 'woff' vs 'woff2' for chrome -- seems to be working. @halfer my firefox supports woff2.

Comment: This is a handy shortcut. Wish google would add format options to the downloads. Another work-around, since I don't see it mentioned anywhere else on this question, is to download the .ttf from Google, and upload it to Font Squirrel's webfont generator: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator which will convert your font to whichever web format you need.

Comment: this is the definite answer.

By doing something like

`curl "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/90.0'`

you get the CSS generated with `woff2` links, whereas passing old versions like

`curl "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/30.0'`

output the older `woff` format.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is using the following ([node](https://nodejs.org/download/)) [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) package: [gulp-google-webfonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-google-webfonts).

Once installed it takes moments to install fonts and create corresponding css.

Note that when installing a Google Font with whitespace in the name, (you don't escape it) reference it with the plus sign as follows:

fonts.list

```
Cabin+Sketch:400
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [everythingfonts.com](https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff) to convert the `ttf` file to a `woff` file.

Comment: Or https://www.transfonter.org